# I am trying to make a decryption function for transposition cipher

Tags: python, encryption

I am supposed to be limited to using the len(), ord(), and range() functions. However, I do not know how I am supposed to meet those requirements and ended up making this:

```
def swap(s: str, index0: int, index1: int):
    smaller = index0 if index0 < index1 else index1
    bigger = index0 if index0 >= index1 else index1
    if bigger >= len(s) or smaller < 0:
        return None
    ret = s[:smaller] + s[bigger] + s[smaller+1:]  # swap first
    ret = ret[:bigger] + s[smaller] + s[bigger+1:] # swap second
    return ret


def swap_encrypt(s: str, key:str):
    ret = s
    for key_chr in key:
        index = ascii_uppercase.index(key_chr)
        swap_this = index % len(ret)
        with_this = (swap_this - 1) % len(ret)
        ret = swap(ret, swap_this, with_this)

    return ret
s = ''
key = ''
def main2():
    s = input('Enter your message: ')
    s = cleanup(s)
    key = input('Enter your keyword: ')
    key = cleanup(key)
    ret= swap_encrypt((s), (key))
    print(cleanup(ret))

main2()
```

When I enter 'Lsoth' for the message and 'a' for the keyword, I get 'HSOTL' instead of 'SLOTH'

Is there a way to meet my requirements while also fixing the my decryption trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def swap_decrypt(msg: str, key: str):
ret = msg
for key_char in key:
    index = ord(key) + ord('A')
    swap_this = index % len(ret)
    with_this = (swap_this + 1) % len(ret)
    ret = swap2(ret, swap_this, with_this)
return ret

def main3():
    msg = input('Enter message for decrpytion: ')
    key = input('Enter keyword for decryption: ')
    msg = cleanup(msg)
    key = cleanup(key)
    ret = swap_decrypt(msg, key)
    print(cleanup(ret))
```

instead of `ascii_uppercase` do `index = ord(key) + ord('A')`, and `(swap_this -1)` should be adding not subtracting by 1. After these minor changes, your issue will be solved. I also changed a few variables in order so that it could make more sense.

Comment: I appreciate the help, thank you!